# Apache vHosts Conf - ErrorLog Custom Paths

Tags: apache, vhosts, error-log

I've got my vhosts conf setup to automate all websites inside my www dir using the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@%0
    ServerName %0
    ServerAlias %0
    VirtualDocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/%0/httpdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

This all works absolutely fine, however I want to add a custom log directory using the %0 variable. I tried doing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@%0
    ServerName %0
    ServerAlias %0
    VirtualDocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/%0/httpdocs
    ErrorLog C:/wamp/www/%0/logs/errors.log
    CustomLog C:/wamp/www/%0/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

However this doesnt work, apache errors when starting up saying

```
(OS 3)The system cannot find the path specified.  : httpd.exe: could not open error log file C:/wamp/www/%0/logs/errors.log.
```

How can I adjust the vhost entry to allow this method of logging?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [mod_macro](http://people.apache.org/~fabien/mod_macro/) could be something for this? I did not try it myself since I do not have that module installed (Third party) but this post from serverfault might be of interest?

[Using variables in Apache config files to reduce duplication?](https://serverfault.com/questions/64656/using-variables-in-apache-config-files-to-reduce-duplication)